# Sequelize can't create with association

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a record with associations from existing records.

For example:

```
        const surveys = await Surveys.create(
          {
            UserToId: args.UserToId,
            UserFromId: args.UserFromId,
            statusId: args.statusId,
            sourceId: args.sourceId,
            link: args.link,
            score: args.score
          },
          {
            include: [
              { model: Users, as: "UseToId" },
              { model: Users, as: "UserFromId" },
              { model: Statuses },
              { model: Sources }
            ]
          }
        );

        console.log("survey:", surveys);
        return surveys;
```

I get the message:

> users is associated to surveys multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include.

It seems like that's what I did in the includes but it's still not allowing me to create the items.

Why can I not create items with just their IDs, I don't understand why I need the include if I just want to insert and ID into a ForeignKey column.

I printed out Survey:

```
dataValues:
   { id: 16,
     statusId: 1,
     sourceId: 1,
     link: 'survey.com/22kj23l',
     score: 4,
     updatedAt: 2019-08-20T00:28:50.511Z,
     createdAt: 2019-08-20T00:28:50.511Z,
     UserToId: null,
     UserFromId: null },
  _previousDataValues:
   { statusId: 1,
     sourceId: 1,
     link: 'survey.com/22kj23l',
     score: 4,
     id: 16,
     createdAt: 2019-08-20T00:28:50.511Z,
     updatedAt: 2019-08-20T00:28:50.511Z,
     toId: undefined,
     fromId: undefined },
```

My model is like this:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const surveys = sequelize.define(
    "surveys",
    {
      link: DataTypes.STRING,
      score: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {}
  );
  surveys.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    models.surveys.belongsTo(models.statuses);
    models.surveys.belongsTo(models.sources);
    models.surveys.belongsTo(models.users, { as: "to" });
    models.surveys.belongsTo(models.users, { as: "from" });
  };
  return surveys;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the `as` values don't match, i.e. "UseToId" <> "to".  It seems you are confusing the table alias and the foreign key field.

Try changing to:

```
 model.surveys.belongsTo(user, {as: 'toUser', foreignKey: 'UseToId'});
```

and

```
include: [
  { model: Users, as: "toUser" },
```

Regarding `models.surveys.belongsTo(models.users, { as: "to" });`: IMHO using a reserved word as an alias should be avoided - it is asking for trouble.